# redirigir la salida de un programa en ejecucion a una segunda pantalla

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

Uso el programa `arandr` para gestionar 2 pantallas, este programa me permite tener una **pantalla principal** en la cual puedo acceder a usar todas las opciones del S0 y otra en la cual no se puede hacer nada, amenos de que la defina como **pantalla principal**, entonces el proceso que hago es:

1. Hacer la SEGUNDA pantalla como **pantalla principal**.
2. abrir `firefox`.
3. Hacer la PRIMERA pantalla como **pantalla principal**.

Con esto lo que consigo hacer es ejecutar todo un programa como `firefox` en la SEGUNDA pantalla y  la PRIMERA tenerla libre para ejecutar los programas que quiera.

Quiero saber como puedo mandar el proceso generado por `firefox` que esta dando salida en la SEGUNDA pantalla para que use su salida en la PRIMERA pantalla.

Lo que se me ocurrió fue pausar el proceso, y luego reanudarlo redirigiendo la salida hacia el dispositivo `PANTALLA1`, pero en ese caso no sabría si esto funcionase ya que no se cual es el nombre de ese dispositivo, pero supondría que esta relacionado con `stdout`:

```sh
$ firefox & 
[1] 13994
$ kill -s SIGSTOP 13994
[1]  + 13994 suspended (signal)  firefox
$ kill -s CONT 13994 > [DispositivoPantalla2]
```

Lo que me faltaría seria el Dispositivo asociado a la SEGUNDA pantalla, ese es lo que quiero intentar, pero si existe alguna mejor manera de hacerlo podrían compartirla o si no ayudarme a encontrar el dispositivo asociado.

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo muy bien el tema de las pantallas pero puedes controlar donde va a aparecer la salida de un proceso usando un `named pipe`. Un `named pipe` es como un archivo que existe en el **FS** pero que se usa para conectar la entrada/salida de dos procesos completamente separados. Digamos:

```
mkfifo ~/pal_firefox
```

Ya tienes la tubería lista para usarse. En un terminal:

```
forefox &> ~/pal_firefox
```

En **otro** terminal completamente separado:

```
cat ~/pal_firefox
```

Y ahí verías la salida de firefox.

Este tipo de cosas brinda mucha flexibilidad. Incluso puedes arrancar el `cat` antes de arrancar `firefox`. Si no me equivoco, si dejas de leer con el `cat`, no se si `firefox` se pausaría cuando el buffer de la pila se llene (resumiendo cuando un proceso siga leyendo de la tubería).